# Close form expression for an integral with z derivative of jacobi theta function

Tags: definite-integrals, elliptic-functions, theta-functions

I have an expression of the form

$$
\tag{1}
A(\chi) = \int_{0}^\infty\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^{i+1}\frac{(2i+1)\chi}{\sqrt{t}}\exp\left(\frac{-(2i+1)^2\chi^2}{t}\right)\mathrm{d}t.
$$

If I am not mistaken, this expression is equal to

$$
\tag{2}
A(\chi) = \frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\chi}{\sqrt{t}}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}\left[\vartheta_3\left(\exp\left(\frac{-\chi^2}{t}\right);\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right]\mathrm{d}t,
$$
where
$$
\tag{3}
\vartheta_3(q;z) = 1+2\sum_{i=1}^\infty q^{i^2}\cos(2iz).
$$

Getting rid of the infinite summation excited me. $\sin(i\pi/2)$ handles both the sign alternation and the vanishing of the summation in (3) for even $i$, which looks neat. But other than the neatness, I cannot proceed any further and this provides only a marginal computational benefit.

I know that

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}\vartheta_3(q;z)}{\mathrm{d}q}=-\frac{1}{4q}\frac{\mathrm{d^2}\vartheta_3(q;z)}{\mathrm{d}z^2},
$$
which might be somehow related. This is why I thought there might be a trick somewhere that requires someone's attention with a better knowledge than I have.

Is there a way to proceed any further for a closed form expression?

Thanks in advance!

Disclaimer: Elaborated "there is no way you can move any further" answers are valid and I can accept such an answer.

Edit: It appears that $A(\chi) \approx \chi^2$. I don't know if this helps.

Comment: I will add more detail in a bit but it appears that $A(\chi)=-\chi^2\sqrt\pi$...

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense. I am pretty sure I have problems with coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I was able to get a seemingly correct answer. I, being a physicist by training, have played very fast and loose with somewhat unfamiliar mathematics here. I am sure, on some level, this is illegitimate. However, we have...

$$A(\chi)=-\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{i}(2i+1)\chi\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-\frac{(2i+1)^2\chi^2}{t}}dt$$

applying the substitution $u=\frac{(2i+1)^2\chi^2}{t}$ yields;

\begin{align}
\tag{1}
A(\chi) &=-\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{i}(2i+1)^2\chi^2\int_{0}^{\infty}u^{-\frac{3}{2}}e^{-u}du\\
\tag{2}
&=-\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{i}(2i+1)^2\chi^2\Gamma\big(-\frac{1}{2}\big)\\
\tag{3}
&=2\chi^2\sqrt{\pi}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{i}(2i+1)^2
\end{align}

Now, we can write the remaining sum thusly...

\begin{align}
\tag{4} &\space\space\space\space\space \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{i}(2i+1)^2\\
\tag{5}
&=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{i}(4i^2+4i+1)
\end{align}

Which gives us;

\begin{align}
\tag{6}
 &= 4\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{i}i^2+4\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{i}i+\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{i}\\
\tag{7}
&=-4\eta(-2)-4\eta(-1)+\eta(0)=0-1+\frac{1}{2}=-\frac{1}{2}
\end{align}

So our final answer, which I have investigated and confirmed numerically, appears to be...

$$\tag{8} A(\chi)=2\chi^2\sqrt{\pi}(-\frac{1}{2})=-\chi^2\sqrt{\pi}$$

Again, I have not been careful about interchanging the integral and sum at the start nor have I been careful in my application of known Dirichlet eta function values to a classically non-convergent sum. So, whatever outrage this may cause among the actual mathematicians is well deserved.

Comment: I assume you have $\mathrm{d}u$ instead of $\mathrm{d}t$ in (1)? Also, (7) might be justified with Cesaro sum, but I am myself an electronics engineer so don't take my word for it :) I will accept this shortly, after going through the $u$ substitution. It fits my empirical results and rigorous enough for me.

Comment: @ck1987pd Yes, I did mean $du$. Thank you for catching that. Glad to hear it's good enough for your purposes. I'm still pretty fuzzy on when the results of analytic continuation can be "safely" extended to series that naively diverge.

Comment: Btw, I plan to cite this answer in a paper. I just wanted to give you a heads up :)

Comment: @ck1987pd Thats awesome... What is the paper about if I may ask?

Comment: Sure, it is about rate of absorption in molecular communications. $\alpha\chi^2$ is the expected time to the first incidence, given the motion starts at the centre of a 1D domain and obeys Brownian Motion. Probably some mathematician derived this but decided it is not worthy of publishing, because I couldn't find this in spite of combing the literature for a very long time, so I had to do it myself.

Comment: If other authors concur, I will cite this as "A more rigorous proof of our empirical observations can be found here"

Comment: @ck1987pd Interesting... Glad I could offer some help! Good luck on the paper.